# Check if String is a Dualnumber using if and while methods

Tags: java, string, if-statement, while-loop, char

when I run these methods it returns true no matter what the Input is and I haven't been able to figure out why this happens for the life of me. The code above is probably the 60th iteration I've tried and nothing has worked out so far. Help is appreciated

So I have the first while loop go from the first Index of the String to the last, then I assign n to a character c. After that I open another while loop which is gonna go from 2 to 9 and assign  the variable y to the character b and then for each loop Im checking if the characters match and if they do its supposed to return false since a dualnumber may only consist of 1 and 0.

```
public static boolean istDualZahl(String zahl)
    {
        
        int n = 0;
            while(n <= zahl.length()) {
                
                Character c = zahl.charAt(n);
                    
                    int y = 2;
                    while(y <= 9) {
                        Character b = (char) y;
                        if(c.equals(b)) {
                            return false;
                            
                        }
                        y++;
                        }
                    n++;
                    
            }
        
            
        return true;    
    }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(istDualZahl("101010"));//Sollte true sein
        System.out.println(istDualZahl("123"));//Sollte false sein
        
    }
```

should return true and then false.

Comment: When I run this code I get a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6` and not the `true` return value you claim to get.

Comment: But, after changing the condition to `n < zahl.length` i think i see what you mean and your real problem is: You aren't converting your integer to chars correctly. `(char) 2` is not the same as `'2'`.  The int values of chars correspond to the [Ascii value](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) where `'2'` has the int value of `50`. A quick fix for your code would be to directly use chars as a data type: `char y = '2'` -> `while (y <= '9')`

Comment: What the hell do you call a dual number?

Comment: OK, so I guess what you call a dual number is actually a binary number

Comment: Try `Character b = (char) (y + '0');`

Comment: Try this instead: `return zahl.matches(".*(.).*\\1.*"); ` if you want to detect duplicate digits, or `return zahl.matches(".*[2-9].*");` if you want to detect digits 2-9.

Comment: Don’t use `Character` at places where a `char` would do. Using `equals` with an `int` value will always fail because you end up comparing an `Integer` with a `Character`. In contrast, comparing `char` with `int` (just use `==` instead of `equals`) may succeed if the values match. And rethink you logic. You want to check whether the string solely consists of `'1'` and `'0'` values, so check for precisely that, instead of checking for other characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static boolean istDualZahl(String zahl) {
    for(int n = 0; n < zahl.length(); ++n) {
        char c = zahl.charAt(n);
        if (c >= '2' && c <= '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Works for the sample input, but is strongly discouraged. The string is a binary number if it consists of `'1'` and `'0'` only and that’s what the method should check. Just consider what happens when `"abc"` is passed to the method.

Comment: @Holger yes. I assumed that was the expected behaviour.